# Trouble writing array of objects to Firestore collection as separate documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Making a simple get request in Node which returns the following data structure:

```
    {
        "query": {
            "q": "some value",
            "tbm": "some value",
            "location": "some value",
            "gl": "some value",
            "hl": "some value",
            "num": "some value",
            "url": "some value"
        },
        "related_searches": [],
        "results": [
            {
                "title": "some value",
                "link": "www.someValue.com",
                "date": "some value",
                "source": "some value",
                "description": "some value",
                "thumbnail": "some value",
    }
    {
                "title": "some value",
                "link": "www.someValue.com",
                "date": "some value",
                "source": "some value",
                "description": "some value",
                "thumbnail": "some value",
    }
    ]
}
```

When I do the following to write to Firestore, the entire array is written to the Collection in a single document. So I end up with one Document, containing an array with dozens of nested Objects. The goal is to write each nested object to its own document. What am I missing?

```
request(options, function(error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  const responseData = JSON.parse(response.body);
  return db.collection("collection_name").add(responseData);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to loop over it like this:

```
for(let i=0;i<responseData.length;i++){
db.collection("name").add(responseData[i])
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks @R3FL3CT.